# How do I keep my async method from blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm writing a method that is supposed to process a large amount of strings and update the UI for every string processed. I'm using the `async-await` pattern for this using a Progress reporter that reports a string to the main thread where it is supposed to be updated.
The problem is: it doesn't work. The UI gets blocked as if the method was running synchronously, even though I used the await keyword.
Here's what my code looks like:

```
private async Task ProcessFile(string filePath, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        string[] LinesToProcess = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        int LineCount = Buffer.Count();

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < Buffer.Count(); i++)
           {
               //Do actual processing here
               progress.Report(string.Format("Lines processed: {0} / {1}", i, LineCount));
           }
       });
    }
```

And here's the method calling the `ProcessFile` Task

```
private async Task RunTask()
    {
        string filePath = //Get filePath somehow
        await ProcessFile(filePath, new Progress<string>(line =>
            {
                ProcessedLabel.Text = line;
            }));
    }
```

And finally, here's the button callback that the RunTask() Task is related to:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await RunTask();
    }
```

I simplified the code for readability. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(filePath);` is going to do just that, read all lines, so if there are allot of lines you are better off reading line by line. That may help. I'm only new to Async myself

Comment: Have you ever tried to add ConfigureAwait(false) to the ProcessFile function call, I saw UI blocks because of that a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. You're processing many lines so quickly that the UI thread is kept busy updating and has no time to actually display the results. To fix this, don't report progress for every line, but only every 100, 1000, or whethever number of lines is appropriate for you. As an alternative, you could report progress based on time, for example every second. But that would require more complicated code.
2. You're running into an issue with `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, where it runs on the UI thread, because that's the `Current` `TaskScheduler`. Though I don't see any indication in your code that this is the case, so I don't think this is likely. But you should use `Task.Run()` instead to be on the safe side anyway. For more information, read [*StartNew is Dangerous* from Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: Why the downvote? While I agree `Task.Run` is better, the UI blocking issue is almost certainly due to (1). This is because [UI message loops on Windows are prioritized, and `WM_PAINT` is the lowest priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#quequed_messages).

Comment: So I tried both options, and none of these seem to solve the problem. Updating the UI every 100 or so runs of the `for` loop makes the code run a lot faster, but the UI still gets blocked.

Also, I've tried using the debugger, and if I set a breakpoint at the `ProcessedLabel.Text = newReport;` line, I see that, by stepping over it, that line gets called continuously, even if I set it to update every 100 runs!

Comment: @CRefice Then try 1000, or even more. It looks like your processing is very fast, you have to set the number based on that. And if you see line being active in the debugger, but it does not have any effect, then that's very likely just a debugger glitch.